# Function that returns the closest number to B that's in an UNSORTED multidimensional array, A?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

As the title states, I want to create a function that'll take a multidimensional array A, and a number B, that ultimately returns the number in A that is the closest to B. If the number B is in A, then return it. If there's 2 numbers in A that are equally distant from B, choose the first one by counting from row to row.

This is the code I have so far:

```
import numpy as np
def g_C(A,B):
  A = np.asanyarray(A)
  assert A.ndim == 2 # to assert that A is a multidimensional array.
  get = (np.abs(A-B)).argmin()
  return (A[get])
```

However from my understanding, I think `(np.abs(M-N)).argmin()` really only effectively works for sorted arrays? I'm not allowed to sort the array in this problem; I have to work on it for face value, examining row by row, and grabbing the first instance of the closest number to B.

So for example, `g_C([[1,3,6,-8],[2,7,1,0],[4,5,2,8],[2,3,7,10]],9)` should return `8`

Also, I was given the hint that `numpy.argmin` would help, and I see that it's purpose is to extract the first occurrence something occurs, which makes sense in this problem, but I'm not sure how exactly to fit that into the code I have at the moment.

EDIT
The flat suggestion works perfectly fine. Thank you everyone.

I'm trying RagingRoosevelt's second suggestion, and I'm stuck.

```
def g_C(A,B):
  A = np.asanyarray(A)
  D = np.full_like(A, B) # created an array D with same qualities as array A, but just filled with values of B
  diffs = abs(D-A) # finding absolute value differences between D and A
  close = diffs.argmin(axis=1) # find argmin of 'diffs', row by row
  close = np.asanyarray(close) # converted the argmins of 'diff' into an array
  closer = close.argmin() # the final argmin ??
  return closer
```

I'm trying out this suggestion because I have another problem related to this where I have to extract the row who's sum is the closest number to B. And I figure this is good practice anyway.

Comment: This is just linear-search (O(n) is a lower bound). Either loop once cleverly (unvectorized) or do 2 passes: differences to b in vectorized op 1. Then argmin. The multidimensional part is a bit inconclusive. Assuming you want to work on all values your tiebreaking depends on the flattening-order (row-col vs. col-row). **Edit:** ok, you mentioned by it to be row-wise.

Comment: "However from my understanding, I think (np.abs(M-N)).argmin() really only effectively works for sorted arrays?" - I don't think this is the case - do you have a source that suggests this?

Comment: *"I think (np.abs(M-N)).argmin() really only effectively works for sorted arrays?"* No.  `argmin()` works fine for unsorted arrays.

Comment: Change `return (A[get])` to `return A.flat[get]` and you're done.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your existing code is fine except, by default, `argmin` returns an index to the flattened array. So you could do

```
return A.flat[abs(A - B).argmin()]
```

to get the right value from A.

EDIT: For your other problem - finding the row in a 2-dimensional array A whose sum is closest to B - you can do:

```
return A[abs(A.sum(axis=1) - B).argmin()]
```

In either case I don't see any need to create an array of B.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is the same as a find-min problem.  The only difference is that you're looking for `min(abs(A[i]-B))` instead.  So, iterate over your array.  As you do so, record the smallest absolute delta and the index at which it occurred.  When you find a smaller delta, update the record and then keep searching.  When you've made it all the way through, return whatever value was at the recorded index.

Since you're working with numpy arrays, another approach is that you could create an array of identical size as `A` but filled only with value `B`.  Compute the difference between the arrays and then use `argmin` on each row.  Assemble an array of all minimum values for each row and then do argmin again to pull out the smallest of the values.

Comment: If you don't mind, I'm trying out your second suggestion, and I'm a little confused about the last sentence. How would I go about ensuring that it's the original position of the A array that's extracted and not the values of the differences? This is what I got so far:

Comment: `def g_C(A,B):
    A = np.asanyarray(A)
    D = np.full_like(A, B) # created an array D with same qualities as array A, but just filled with values of B
    diffs = abs(D-A) # finding absolute value differences between D and A
    close = diffs.argmin(axis=1) # find argmin of 'diffs', row by row
    close = np.asanyarray(close) # converted the argmins of 'diff' into an array
    closer = close.argmin() # the final argmin ??
    return closer`

Comment: sorry that looks ugly, should I edit it into my original question?

Comment: @zainy,  
I think Stuart has a better answer than mine and does essentially what my second paragraph suggested.

Comment: Yeah but I'm kinda having trouble figuring out how to adapt Stuart's answer into a similar problem of extracting the row in a multidimensional array, that sums to the closest number to B

Comment: Hey, @zainy, still having troubles with Stuart's answer?  He edited it to address your other problem, too.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any `2-dimensional` array with a nested `for-loop`, but I am not sure that this is what you want (as in it doesn't use `numpy`).

```
def g_C(A, B):
    i = A[0][0]
    m = abs(B - A[0][0])
    for r in A:
        for i in r:
            if abs(B - i) < m:
                m = abs(B - i)
                n = i
    return n
```

Nevertheless, it does work:

```
>>> g_C([[1,3,6,-8],[2,7,1,0],[4,5,2,8],[2,3,7,10]],9)
8
```