# Function that returns the row in an UNSORTED multidimensional array, A, that sums to the closest number to B?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, multidimensional-array

Related to my other recent question [Function that returns the closest number to B that's in an UNSORTED multidimensional array, A?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47718072/function-that-returns-the-closest-number-to-b-thats-in-an-unsorted-multidimensi?noredirect=1#comment82397016_47718072)

What I've made sense of so far:

```
import numpy as np
def get_R(A,B):
  A = np.asanyarray(A)
  assert A.ndim == 2
  sums = A.sum(axis=1)
  close = sums.argmin(B)
  return A.flat[close]
```

I'm being returned an error `ValueError: axis(=9) out of bounds`

for `get_r([[1,3,6,-8],[2,7,1,0],[4,5,2,8],[2,3,7,10]],9)`

when I should be getting `array([2,7,1,0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the following modification to your function

```
def get_R(A,B):
  A = np.asanyarray(A)
  assert A.ndim == 2
  sums = A.sum(axis=1)
  sums = abs(sums - B)
  close = sums.argmin()
  return A[close,:]
```

There were two changes made here.

First we replace sums with abs(sums - B) before we call the `argmin()` function. This is a correct way to get the element of the sums array that is closer to `B`.

Second we return `A[close,:]` which is a correct way to get a row out of a 2D array.

#### Tracing the execution

Let's examine how this works line by line

```
>>> A=np.asanyarray([[1,3,6,-8],[2,7,1,0],[4,5,2,8],[2,3,7,10]])
>>> sums = A.sum(axis=1)
>>> sums
array([ 2, 10, 19, 22])
>>> abs(sums - 9) 
array([ 7,  1, 10, 13])
>>> abs(sums - 9).argmin()
1
>>> A[1,:]
array([2, 7, 1, 0])
```

#### Your error message

The error message `ValueError: axis(=9) out of bounds` was reported because `numpy.argmin(self, axis=None, out=None)` when called as a method of a Numpy array treats its argument as an `axis` argument. Calling `axis = 9` on a vector is certainly an error.